# Angularjs busy indicator for filter

Tags: angularjs

Busy indicators are aplenty for $http.

I have filters that can take 2 or 3 seconds on cell phones.
I'd like to 'busy' the display until Angular is through doing its stuff (filter AND redraw what it needs to), so users don't click again.

Is there an event I can subscribe to that would help me wire this up?

Comment: You should be aware that filters in angularjs should be short, because angular calls them very often. Look at this simple example http://jsfiddle.net/mchrobok/eappK/1/. In console you can see how many times filter is invoked. Angular calls filter during every $digest so they are invoked even if you click button. I think it will hang your application if your filter executes 2seconds.

Comment: I also prepared another jsfiddle with my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mchrobok/8Xq4d/7/. Unfortunatelly, mask is not visible unless you set breakpoint before mask will be hidden. I don't know why, because logs in console are correct - messages "show/hide mask" are shown correctly.

Comment: My application runs fine.  And its probably not my filter but Angular which takes the time to re display the updated content.  I'm just asking for a way to 'busy' the display. I did this originally by getting the update from the server (lots of busy indicators for that).  Seems like a waste when angular can do it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you need an event? I don't think there is one, but you could consider just wrapping all of your filter functions in a generic busy indicator wrapper.

```
function busyWrap(func) {
  return function() {
    Busy.start();
    try {
      func.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
    } finally {
      Busy.stop();
    }
  }
};
```

Then in your filter definitions change something like this

```
app.filter('filter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return output;
  };
});
```

to this

```
app.filter('filter', function() {
  return busyWrap(function(input) {
    return output;
  });
});
```

The code may not be perfect but the idea of a reusable function that will wrap filter functions is your best bet. It is highly likely, though, that the code taking the most time is internal to angular (such as redrawing a large ng-repeat on a sorted list), so this may not help you out.

Comment: I tried something similar (not as elegant) and it didn't do the job.  I'll update the question so 'doing its stuff' is more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a directive BusyIndicator IsBusy="IsBusySubmitting || IsBusyLoadingTemplate"

I can control the busy indicator layer through the controller scope this way.

https://twitter.com/leblancmeneses/statuses/341368016556142594

Comment: The BusyIndicator itself is not my question (there are many examples available). My issue is how to deactivate it when angular is through processing my filter.

Comment: to know when to deactivate something - you need to use promise api.  The logic for my busyindicator resides in a controller.